# How can I solve R.layout.main cannot be resolved in my android apps?

Tags: android

Im new as a developer of Android apps. I find a problem. that is R.layout.main cannot be resolved. How can I solve my problem. my code is here. please solve my problem.

```
 package com.android;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HelloActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    Button bt;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonOk);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Welcome Android World", 3000).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(HelloActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}




*
```

> **and my xml code is here:**

*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Ok" android:id="@+id/ButtonOk" android:height="50dp" android:width="100dp"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove import `android.R;` and press `CTRL + SHIFT + O` for importing your on application R

Comment: besides the comment above, clean the project in eclipse and build again. This question is a neverending duplicate

Comment: this has been answered a hundred times.. please google before you ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 11):

**Step 1** : Remove `import android.R;`

**Step 2** : `Clean And Rebuild` (It should work)

**If not**

Then `close the project` exits eclipse and open again. Follow the steps it should work.

**If not**

Change your package

**From**

`import android.R;`

**To**

`import yourpackage.R;`

It Should work

Answer (score 7):

Remove the line import android.R from the header.

and do a Ctrl + Shift + O

If android.R appears again, then manually write

```
import <yourpackagename>.R
```

Looks like you used the package name as com.android.R. Ideally speaking, avoid using package names like com.android. Try to maintain it like
com.companyname.appname

So you get into that habit, and don't have the pain of changing the package name in all the folders once you are about to publish.

Answer (score 1):

Import com.android.R not android.R because your package name is com.android

Answer (score 0):

Try to Clean and Rebuild your application and this should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

my friend,
check that whether name of your xml file is "main" because we always write setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file_name);
If you find my solution worthy then please like it

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem on IntelliJ IDEA and this is how I was able to solve the problem, but first I noticed the following:

1. this problem did not hinder the execution of the application
2. the resource file (R.java) located in the **out/production/my/package/name** directory is automatically updated, but the resource file (R.java) located in the **gen/my.package.name** directory is not updated automatically
3. IntelliJ IDEA uses the non-updated R.java for intellisence

So, I copied the layout class that was generated in R.java file in **out/production/my/package/name** directory, as below

```
public static final class layout {
    public static final int main = 2130903040;

    public layout() {
    }
}
```

and I pasted this into the R.java file in **gen/my.package.name** directory

**NOTE:**
Please, and please, don't modify the auto-generated resource file **R.java** file in **out/production/my/package/name**